# WCF - How to monitor

Tags: c#, wcf, monitoring

I am currently looking into a way of monitoring my WCF layer so that if a certain web method isn't called within a certain time frame, then send me an email.  The reason being is my services should be hit at regular intervals, and if they aren't i want an email to inform me.

Is there some **light** library or framework that allows this, or some third party program.

My initial idea was to use AOP to log each web method request to a database table.  Then have a separate windows service that would look at this db table and tell me when a certain method wasn't called for over an hour for example.

Comment: A suggestion is to use a logging library (maybe log4net) and simple windows task. You don`t need a windows service.

Comment: that would involve adding logging to each web service though yes?  I was looking for a solution to deal with cross cutting concerns

Comment: No, you can use an AOP approach with any logging library.

Comment: How is it possible with log4net to log to a database all calls to  WCF  web methods in a certain namespace using AOP?  Do you have an example of this? Thanks by the way"!

Comment: You can use WCF Interceptors for logging. You can find example [https://stackoverflow.com/a/57818618/5519709](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57818618/5519709)